# Como executar jobs sequencialmente no Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Boa tarde,

Possuo um projeto onde existem 10 jobs e gostaria de saber como faço para executar todos em sequencia ( Executo o primeiro e mesmo se der erro, ele continua a execução até ter finalizado todos os jobs )

Verifiquei que existem alguns plugins mas como não conheço muito bem, gostaria da ajuda de alguem aqui da comunidade.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O jenkins tem a opção de [usar pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), que é o que você está procurando. No exemplo abaixo que extraí da documentação, esse pipeline possui 3 estágios: `build`, `test` e `deploy`. Porém você pode adicionar quantos estágios desejar:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('JobA') {
            steps {
                echo 'Comandos relacionado com o job a'
            }
        }
        stage('JobB') {
            steps {
                echo 'Comandos relacionado com o job b'
            }
        }
        stage('JobC') {
            steps {
                echo 'Comandos relacionado com o job c'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oi Marabesi, obrigado pela ajuda. Desculpe mas sou meio novato nesse meio hahaha.

Comment: Marabesi poderia me explicar como ficaria esse codigo + ou - com o nome dos jobs ? exemplo "JobA", "JobB"  etc..

Comment: Editei a resposta pra tentar ilustrar melhor

Comment: Só complementando... no github tem uns exemplos bacanas que podem te dar um norte: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples

Comment: Oi Marabesi bom dia, obrigado. Nessa linha do echo, nao sei que comando seria utilizado para dar start no job

Comment: pode usar o comando `build 'Job1' // nome do job`, para descobrir o nome do job que quer chamar, digo o caminho correto, acesse o job, e copie o nome completo do projeto.